# how to display a media description in a twig template?

Tags: 8, theming, media

i want to display the media description available in the file field of a media ( media of type video, audio, image, etc...), it is an option to activate:

> Enable Description field
>
> The description field allows users to enter a description about the uploaded file.

i already print other fields that i want in the media twig template, but i can not find the value of that "description" field attribute, because it's not a field, but some sort of attribute of the file field.

Answer (score 1):

I got the media description in the preprocess

```
function template_preprocess_media(array &$variables) {

  $bundle = $media->Bundle();

  if($bundle == 'file') {
    $field_media_file = $variables['content']["field_media_file"];
 
    if($field_media_file[0]["#description"]){
      $desc = $field_media_file[0]["#description"];
    } else{
      $desc = $variables['name'];
    }
    $variables['description'] = $desc;
  }
}
```